# "Property exception component:'wordPruningSearchManager' property:'logMath' - mandatory property is not set" in CMU-Sphinx

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am getting this error when i try to run below code of CMU-Sphinx Acoustic Model
Exception is :-

> Exception in thread "main" Property exception
>   component:'wordPruningSearchManager' property:'logMath' - mandatory
>   property is not set!

Full stack trace is :-

```
Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'wordPruningSearchManager' property:'logMath' - mandatory property is not set!
edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException: mandatory property is not set!
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponentFromAnnotation(PropertySheet.java:313)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:301)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.newProperties(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:201)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:505)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:287)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.newProperties(AbstractDecoder.java:65)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.newProperties(Decoder.java:37)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:505)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:287)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.newProperties(Recognizer.java:90)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:505)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:161)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:73)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:44)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.<init>(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:37)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer.<init>(LiveSpeechRecognizer.java:33)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.keval.test.accosticTest.AccosticTest.main(AccosticTest.java:26)
```

My code is :

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;

public class AccosticTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Loading models...");
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/en_accostic_model");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/cmudict.0.6d");
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/hellongram/hellongram.trigram.lm");
    LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
    recognizer.startRecognition(true);
    SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
    System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using corrupted and/or outdated source